# Forward [open] Ports 7777; 2106

Tags: networking, server, firewall, iptables

Hi i am new to Ubuntu (12.10) x64
Trying to forward ports for gameserver on my pc (Lineage II)
Ports are opened in UFW 
Ports are opened in my Router
Even if i disable UFW others still cant login to gameserver 
Tried most [Terminal] commands to forward ports still wont open
I have the server opened which should make ports liste and they should appear to be open in sites like canyouseeme.ogr

Also tried some commands to open them in 'iptables' 
im so confused help

Comment: Could you specify your network configuration? Is the Ubuntu machine your gameserver or your router? Or even something entirely else?

Comment: Ye i am behind D-Link DIR-501 router, the ubuntu machine is the gameserver host, using static IP adress,

Comment: What does your Ubuntu machine do? Why do you wnt to forward ports on it?

Comment: the ubuntu machine is the gameserver host, using static IP adress,

Comment: Then you don't need port forwarding on it. You just need to forward ports to it on your router. It's possible you messed up your network configuration while trying to do so.

Comment: i has run the same server under windows. until then, i didnt forwared ports in windows firewall, no1 was able to connect to server. right now is the same...

Comment: Use `netstat -tulpn` to see if your Ubuntu machine is listening on those ports.

Comment: No, i can't see them in list

Comment: then it's highly likely your gameserver software doesn't start correctly.

Comment: I dont see any errors either in gameserver console thats why i think my problems are with ports itself

Answer (score 1):

Please try the next workaround, after which and depending on your results, this answer may be deleted or improved. Thank you. I know this is not a forum but I provide this as an answer because of it works for me when setting up a WAN Game Server for Team Fortress 2 and it -indeed- does an excellent work.

First of all you need to install firestarter if haven't yet. Please drop `sudo apt-get install firestarter` in a terminal, provide your password and wait for the install to finish.

Next, let's run firestarter with administrative privileges by dropping `gksudo firestarter` in the terminal. After which we'll be asked for our user password in GUI. Then the firestarter window will appear, as shown in the next screenshot:

[image]

Let's clic the "Policy" Tab in order to add the proper ports or port lists that your game needs by right clicking on the second list (Allow service/Port/For)  and choose "Add Rule" as shown in the next screenshot:

[image]

We'll see the "Add new inbound rule" in which we'll fill the data fields with the proper values in order to allow the port's calls hit the computer's ports.

[image]

The service's ports will be added to the list, after which you can reach your game server with no difficulty.

If you are experiencing some kind of issue, you can also temporally stop the Firewall in the top side of the "Status" Tab or via Menu "Firewall" option "Stop Firewall" (Ctrl+P also does the trick). This way you can check if your router is dropping the external petitions to your computer, after which you can solve your computer's ports issue.

Please let us know how are you managing this issue in order to modify/delete this question if doesn't work for you.

Good luck!

Comment: When i type 'gksudo firestarter' and type my pwd, some error appears (Firestarter error) Failed to open the system log.

Comment: did you try turning off your firewall via firestarter? Please inform. Thank you.